# Help with what optimisation technique to use

Tags: optimization

For this equation, I was wondering if I could get some help on how to optimise this (minimising surface area with volume as a constraint)

Equation to be optimised (I was trying to take a partial derivative for one of the steps):https://imgur.com/a/N325gZq

The equation expresses the surface area of an egg shape, and the parentheses are the constraints of volume. I am trying to minimise the surface area whilst keeping the volume constant as part of constrainted optimisation, so I have expressed the formula of volume with another term since it is constant.

In the image, I tried symbolab but it did not work, and I am unclear of my direction from here. I have heard of this technique called numerical optimisation but am not sure if it would apply here.

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: The opposite problem (maximizing the volume for a given area) would probably be simpler